# How to add Chinese into beamer slides

Tags: r, markdown

Rmarkdown and knitr are powerful tools to efficiently generate dynamic documents. However, it seems that it doesn't support Chinese by default for PDF. Luckily,Yihui,Yi Xuan and Yu Miao have offered a solution for this (https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/ctex/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd). Here I wonder how I can understand the following lines and how I can revise them accordingly to satisfy other purposes. For instance, what if I want to generate beamer slides using beamer_presentation output?

```
documentclass: ctexart
output:
  rticles::ctex:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
classoption: "hyperref,"
```